# For names sake - Project Euler 22

Tags: programming-challenge, file, julia

## [Project Euler - 22](https://projecteuler.net/problem=22)

### Names scores

> Using [`names.txt`](https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p022_names.txt) (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text
>     file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it
>     into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for
>     each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the
>     list to obtain a name score.
>
> For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, `COLIN`,
>     which is worth \$3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53\$, is the 938th name in the
>     list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of \$938 × 53 = 49714\$.
>
> What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

---

While being fairly comfortable with the zen of Python, Julia is very new to me. Is the following code in line with Julia's vision?

In particular I feel my handling of the dictionary is sub-optimal and especially the way i hard-code remove the parenthesis in names.

Every hint on how to improve the code is welcome.

---

```
ALPHABET_INDEX = Dict( letter => index for (index, letter) in enumerate('A':'Z'))

function namescore(name)
    return sum(ALPHABET_INDEX[letter] for letter in name[2:end-1])
end


function sort_file(filename)
    file = open(filename)
    sort(split(readstring(filename),","))
end


function PE_022(filename="p022_names.txt")

    total = 0
    for (index, name) in enumerate(sort_file(filename))
        total += index*namescore(name)
    end
    total
end

println(PE_022())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only change I would make is to remove your use of the `Dict`. Dicts are great when you need mutability, but here there is the much simpler solution `Int(letter)-Int('A')`. With this change, `namescore` becomes

```
function namescore(name)
    return sum(Int(char)-Int('A') for letter in name[2:end-1])
end
```

This, however is not ideal, as we can take out the subtraction, yielding

```
function namescore(name)
    return sum(Int(char) for letter in name[2:end-1]) - (lenth(name)-2) * Int('A')
end
```

I haven't done performance testing, but this should be a fair bit faster, as I would expect `Int` to be faster than a dictionary lookup.

Comment: I just used  'BenchmarkTools' , and saw no noticable change in performance. [Here are the results](https://pastebin.com/TKhcbU3T), and [here are the functions tested](https://pastebin.com/QeF1aCgc).

However I do agree that using 'Int(letter)' is much cleaner. Perhaps dictionaries in Julia are fairly optimized compared to Python?

Comment: Pretty sure you want `Int(char) - Int('A') + 1`, and a similar change for your second version, since `'A'` should evaluate to `1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem a few months ago, here's the code I used:

```
name_scores_total() = name_scores_total(@__DIR__()*"/022data_names.txt")
name_scores_total(names_file::String) = name_scores_total(vec(readdlm(names_file, ',', String)))

function name_scores_total(names_list::Array{String})
    sort!(names_list)
    alphabet_order = Dict((c, UInt8(c) - UInt8('A') + 1) for c in 'A':'Z')

    total_score = 0
    for (pos, name) in enumerate(names_list)
        try
            name_score = pos * sum(alphabet_order[c] for c in name)
            total_score += name_score
        catch er
            er isa KeyError && error("Only CAPITAL English letters are allowed in the file ($(name) has $(er.key) in it)")
            rethrow()
        end
    end

    total_score
end

if !isinteractive()
    println(name_scores_total())
end
```

Pretty similar to what your code does when it comes down to it (the main loop), but uses multiple dispatch to allow different types of input, and uses `readdlm` to read the file, which automatically strips the quotes around the input fields.

I can't say for sure that this is a "better" way of doing things since I'm also still getting a feel for the language, but at the least it just offers a different approach.